# I am unable to see a toast message for any of the conditions that I've specifed in my broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I have specified all the actions in my manifest.xml file. I am trying to catch them in my Broadcast receiver onReceive but I'm unable to see them.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Sample broadcast receiver boot completed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            Toast.makeText(context,"power connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            Toast.makeText(context,"power disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: have you registered your receiver in code ?

Comment: try with try to add android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"

Comment: @VivekMishra I have registered my receiver in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive a `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent in your application you should add this permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml` :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

As described in Android SDK's documentation:

> If you don't request this permission, you will not receive the broadcast at that time.

You can learn more about that permission here: [android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED)

Comment: So as far as I guess, for `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` you should try to log something and filter the LogCat depending on that value. I won't count on toast. Another thing I think you should register a receiver for `Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and without that you won't receive the intent. More about this: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring

Comment: And can you post your whole `AndroidManifest.xml` file so I can see where are you declaring the receiver?